# On finding a lower bound for the condition number of invertible matrices on $\mathbf{C}^{n \times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

In Linear Algebra discussion here, I see there is some good interest in the Frobenius norm (also called Hilbert-Schmidt norm) of matrices.

I read an interesting paper giving an upper-bound for the condition number of a matrix $A$ in Frobenius norm:

Heinrich W. Guggenheimer, Alan S. Edelman & Charles R. Johnson (1995) A Simple Estimate of the Condition Number of a Linear System, The College Mathematics Journal, 26:1, 2-5, DOI: 10.1080/07468342.1995.11973657

I often thought that instead of an upper-bound, if we could get a lower-bound for the condition number of an invertible matrix, it will be more useful in applications.

I came to know of a conjecture made on Frobenius norm on matrices by Sloane and Harwit (1976). A recent paper by Limin Zou (2012) proved this conjecture for a special class of matrices..

Zou's Theorem: Let $A = [ a_{ij} ]$ be a nonsingular matrix in $\mathbf{C}^{n \times n}$ and suppose that $$0 \leq | a_{ij} | \leq 1$$ for all values of $i$ and $j$. If
$$
\Vert A \Vert_F \leq {\sqrt{n^3 + n^2 - n - 1} \over n},
$$
then
$$
\Vert A^{-1} \Vert \geq {2 n \over n + 1}
$$

(Reference: Zou, L. (2012). On a conjecture concerning the Frobenius norm of matrices. Linear and Multilinear Algebra, 60(1), 27–31.)

As an application of this result, we get
$$
\kappa(A, F) \geq {2 n \Vert A \Vert_F \over n + 1}
$$
which gives a lower bound for the condition number of $A$ in Frobenius norm.

Zou used Hilbert's matrices to explain his result and I also checked with some test matrices for condition numbers. Zou's result (2012) is interesting.

I like to know if there are any other lower bounds for the condition number of matrices with respect to Frobenius norm or any other norm, which can be easily computed for readily testing the conditioning of matrices, and how do they compare with Zou's 2012 result.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm so what's the question?

Comment: I agree that my question was not clear - I fully changed the question title and added a last line in the body - Hope this change has improved clarity.